# How to set Margins in class inherited from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, margin

How can I set margins in class extends from RelativeLayout?
I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    int margin = 50;

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLook();
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLook();
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLook();
    }

    private void setLook() {
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

How should I do this?

#### Update:

Usage of this view:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <info.korzeniowski.widget.MyRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    //content
    </info.korzeniowski.widget.MyRelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what does it mean that it does not work?

Comment: Do you maybe confuse margin with padding? Please explain what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @blackbelt That means it makes no effect.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I'm not, When I use setPadding() it works fine. I need to use margins and I don't know how.

Comment: is it the root layout for your hierarchy ?

Comment: @WojciechKo Why do you need to use margins? Seems rather strange that the custom `View` sets it's own margins. Normally that depends on the layout the `View` is inside. So why can't you use padding? And what are you trying to do in the first place? Margins don't always work, they are ignored by some `Views`.

Comment: I think usually the parent of a view determines its child's layoutparams, so they might be overwritten by the parent. Can you post a snippet of how you add this view to it's parent?

Comment: @WojciechKo And what exactly is keeping you from defining the margins in xml?

Comment: @XaverKapeller when I add line `android:layout_margin="50dp"` to the xml it works. I want to make default value of layout_margin.

Comment: @WojciechKo Than use this, a custom `View` really shouldn't define it's own margins. And your code most likely doesn't work because the `LayoutParams` you set in the constructor are overwritten with new `LayoutParams` when the `View` is added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: @XaverKapeller so it's not possible to set default value of `android:layout_margin` in custom View?

Comment: @WojciechKo it is definitely possible, but you shouldn't. The margins have nothing to do with the custom view. Margins are purely used for layouting. If you use margins to define the look & feel of your `View` then you are doing something wrong and I can promise you that you will only run into problems resulting from this.

Comment: If you tell me what you are trying to do I can explain to you how to do it.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I wanted to make compound view ScrollView + RelativeLayout but I couldn't figure how to make this so I decided to at last make custom RelativeLayout. I don't want to define margins, padding, background In every layout file where I need the same look of RelativeLayout.

Comment: @WojciechKo There is nothing wrong with what you are trying to do, I am just saying that you cannot use margins for that. Use a padding instead, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom `View` should **NEVER** define its own margins. Margins are purely used for layouting and you cannot reliably use them to design your custom `View`.

You can essentially replicate the effect margins have without any of the problems that come with margins by using paddings and a child `View`:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private final int padding;

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Use 50 dip instead of 50 pixels
        this.padding = LayoutHelper.dpToPixel(context, 50);

        setLook();
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Use 50 dip instead of 50 pixels
        this.padding = LayoutHelper.dpToPixel(context, 50);

        setLook();
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Use 50 dip instead of 50 pixels
        this.padding = LayoutHelper.dpToPixel(context, 50);

        setLook();
    }

    private void setLook() {
        setPadding(this.padding, this.padding, this.padding, this.padding);

        final View innerView = ...;
        final LayoutParams innerViewParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        addView(innerView, innerViewParams);
    }
}
```

The `View` called `innerView` should contain all the content you want to display in your custom `View`.

Comment: I need that, the content of `MyRelativeLayout` to be defined in `xml` file. Can I achieve this with your answer?

Comment: It needs a little modification, but yes. To achieve this you have to override `addViewToLayout()` remove the super call and add the `Views` to `innerView` instead. Are you having trouble with a background or something like that? Because if not than you can just simply use a padding. If yes than you should also consider defining an extra layout just for the content and inflate this layout into `innerView`. There are a number of ways to solve this.

Comment: Could you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680131/custom-scrollable-layout-with-default-values I spent a lot of time on this and have no clue how to do this. Non of my ideas works.

Comment: I will take a look, but give me some time, I'm currently on my way home.